# Example for boost::asio for one single packet

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This is my code

Packet.h

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE header;
    TSimplePlayerInformation akSimplePlayerInformation[PLAYER_PER_ACCOUNT];
    DWORD guild_id[PLAYER_PER_ACCOUNT];
    char guild_name[PLAYER_PER_ACCOUNT][GUILD_NAME_MAX_LEN + 1];
    DWORD handle;
    DWORD random_key;
} TPacketGCLoginSuccess;
```

Network.cpp

```
bool CPythonNetworkStream::__RecvLoginSuccessPacket()
{
    TPacketGCLoginSuccess kPacketLoginSuccess;

    if (!Recv (sizeof (kPacketLoginSuccess), &kPacketLoginSuccess))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_PER_ACCOUNT; ++i)
    {
        m_akSimplePlayerInfo[i] = kPacketLoginSuccess.akSimplePlayerInformation[i];
        m_adwGuildID[i] = kPacketLoginSuccess.guild_id[i];
        m_astrGuildName[i] = kPacketLoginSuccess.guild_name[i];
    }

    m_kMarkAuth.m_dwHandle = kPacketLoginSuccess.handle;
    m_kMarkAuth.m_dwRandomKey = kPacketLoginSuccess.random_key;

    if (__DirectEnterMode_IsSet())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        PyCallClassMemberFunc (m_apoPhaseWnd[PHASE_WINDOW_SELECT], "Refresh", Py_BuildValue ("()"));
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is a recv packet from server, and i want to write it with asio.
Someone can give me an example , from where should i start ?

I have a MMORPG game and network it's very slow, i started to rewrite with asio but i need an example from where should i start ?

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the examples you are searching in the page of the official Boost website related to [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html).

In particular you can find a reusable example among the synchronous/asynchronous daytime server and client examples.

The tutorials/examples in the link are related to version 1.60.0 of Boost. If you need the examples for another released version of Boost you can change the link modifying only the version name in the url.